# How to add file to a previously committed changeset in Subversion?

Tags: svn, configuration, version-control

After migrating from TFS to Subversion, we have found out that one of the files (a branch operation) of a changeset is missing. The tool that we have used implemented branching as delete and add operation separately and in this case it missed to add that file.

After hundreds of revisions later we discovered the problem and fixed it immediately by adding the file to latest version.

However I also would like to add that file to the previous changeset (the broken changeset). Is it possible to do that in Subversion?

(Note: I know it is way too hackish, but that revision must also be compilable as it was also a release. Currently I can only checkout that file from a previous revision and check out the remaining files from that revision which seems to be the only possible solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way would be to check out (or [switch to](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html)) that branch/tag, add the file, and commit a new revision.

As for adding it to a previous changeset... it's probably possible, but generally a bad idea.

Comment: +1 (you beat me to it) - this exploits Subversion's treatment of tags as "branches that you never update"